# Multicollinearity and case:predictor ratio problems

Tags: multiple-regression, pca, spss, elastic-net, partial-least-squares

I have 444 cases and 60ish predictors that suffer from collinearity. The predictors fall into three categories (vol, thickness and demographics). I would prefer to subdivide my cases into 4 (age) groups for the analysis to make more sense theoretically, but I am also controlling for age using linear + quadratic terms for vol and linear + cubic terms for thickness (based on a prior paper).

I have no specific rationale for the order of entry except (I think) they need to be in blocks to properly include age terms for the IV categories, and I could run a whole group analysis if I absolutely had to, but would really prefer grouping if I can improve the power.

So far I have tried running a standard linear regression with forced entry but the collinearity is bad. When I subgroup by age my case:predictor ratio is terrible as well. I tried doing a PCA to help reduce my IVs but I’m not sure it’s correct to do subgroup regression using components derived from a whole group PCA. If if I do PCA by subgroups, I don’t have a minimum 5:1 ratio so I’m not sure this is valid either. Either way I ran a regression on the whole group using the components from the PCA and nothing came out.

I tried to do a penalized regression using elastic net but no models are returned. I’m not sure I’m doing it right in the first place (SPSS) and I don’t know the proper parameters I should be using.

Is my next step a partial least squares regression? I downloaded smartPLS3.

What am I missing or doing incorrectly?

ETA

Sure, I was just trying to keep my question on the shorter side.
It’s a linear regression model.

I’m looking at how MRI and demographic measures of various brain regions can be used to predict reading performance in kids age 3-18. I’d like to do subgroup analysis if possible because I’m not convinced that any model would be able to adequately control for age based on the extent of brain changes that happen across the developmental trajectory.

The number of predictors is 69, across three categories (cortical volume, cortical thickness, demographic measures like household income and parental education). Age needs to be corrected for using a linear + quadratic term for cortical volume, and a linear + cubic term for cortical thickness. I could shrink them a bit by excluding some brain regions or demographic variables if needed.

I ran an elastic net regression in SPSS using the CATREG function and no model was returned. I’m not sure I did it correctly, and my textbook has no info, and I couldn’t find anything helpful online.

For the linear regression I ran using the PCA components, the overall model was not significant and neither were any of the coefficients.

Comment: Please provide more details about the hypothesis you're trying to test or the phenomena you're trying to model. Is this a linear regression model? What's the outcome measure? Just specifying "categories" among the "60ish" predictors doesn't provide much information for guidance. And when you say things like "nothing came out" of a modeling approach, it's hard to know what you mean without seeing more details of what went wrong.

Comment: Just updated the question thx

Answer (score 0):

As I'm sure you know multicollinearity is the result of two of your predictors being highly linearly related. This can occur for example if you have two predictors like length of left and right leg.

I would start by looking at your multicollinearity plots to see if you have any predictors that are highly related. You could also do a regression $x_i \sim x_j$, $i \neq j, \text{ for all } x \in \text{ set of predictors }$

as was commented above you would need to provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have a very large problem with case/predictor ratios, at least one that can't be addressed by applying your knowledge of the subject matter and some standard approaches to regression.

First, subgroup analysis makes your case/predictor ratio so low. Don't subgroup, include all cases in a single model. If your knowledge of the subject matter indicates that the associations of some of your predictors might change with age, evaluate *interactions* of *those particular predictors* with age instead. Those interactions will add more effective predictors to the model, but you should end up with much more power than subgroup analysis.

Second, model age and other continuous predictors more flexibly, with restricted cubic splines rather than imposing pre-defined quadratic or cubic fits. Let the data thus show the shapes of those relationships with outcome.

Third, your overall case/predictor ratio isn't great but it's not abysmal. For a reliable model you probably need to reduce the effective number of predictors down to about 30. That preferably can be done directly by using your knowledge of the subject matter. If you can't remove enough that way, do it implicitly with some form of penalization (ridge, LASSO, elastic net, principal-components or partial least-squares regression). My guess is that ridge would handle this problem pretty well. Software-specific help is off-topic here; without more details one can't interpret what's going on when you say things like "no models are returned." For background, Chapter 6 of [An Introduction to Statistical Learning](http://faculty.marshall.usc.edu/gareth-james/ISL/) (ISLR) clearly explains the principles of these penalization methods and provides exercises to cement your knowledge.

Fourth, please recognize that there is a professional aspect to the principles of statistical modeling that is every bit as important as the professional aspects of magnetic-resonance imaging and evaluating language skills. Instead of just jumping to the next potential software tool when one doesn't seem to work, step back a bit and review those principles first. In addition to ISLR, consult for example the resources provided by [Frank Harrell](https://hbiostat.org/) under the BBR and RMS headings.

Finally, it's quite possible that your predictors bear no useful relationship with your measure of reading performance. But you will only be able to determine that if you wisely apply the principles of regression modeling first.

Comment: thanks for your reply. My co-author is very keen on doing a stepwise regression (which returns significant and very high r^2 values at each subgroup) and I would like to avoid doing this because I know stepwise isn't generally considered a valid approach and the models seem very overfitted.

Comment: @AMuscularHydrostat if you want to cut down on the number of predictors, as with stepwise selection, consider LASSO as a principled way to proceed; ISLR presents this well. In fairness, limited _backward_ stepwise can be done in some circumstances with unpenalized regressions, as a late step. See Section 4.12.1 of Harrell's [course notes](https://hbiostat.org/doc/rms.pdf), step 13. Repeating the entire model-building process (including predictor selection if done) on multiple bootstrap samples, testing each model on the full data set, is a good way to check overfitting